# Sound panning not changing

Tags: java, libgdx

I am struggeling currently with the setPan function of the Music class.
I am playing an ogg file and everything works fine but no matter what I provide in the setPan() function from -1.0 to 1.0 nothing works and it always plays at full volume on both sides.
I cant find anything online about this topic.

Inside the resume function:

```
    mMusic.play();  
    mMusic.setLooping(true);    
    mMusic.setPan(-1f,1f);
```

and inside the pause function

```
    mMusic.pause();
```

Comment: Could you post the problem-related code? :)

Comment: Got it fixed. Subclass overwrote the value. But now an other issue: setPan(-1f,1f); makes the music play still on both sides.

Comment: Until now i never used sound, but could it be, that you have to set the pan before playing the sound? Stupid question: Does your hardware support stereo? :P

Comment: I will try this next week. Yeah my Pc does have Stereo-Output and Speakers :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old post, but just in case somebody else hits this -

LibGDX panning only works for Mono files.

http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=14582&p=63714&hilit=panning#p63714